# List collections interface in java

Tags: java, list, indexing

Please find below a function in my code:

```
    private static List<String> formCrfLinesWithMentionClass(int begin, int end, String id, 
        List<String> mList, int mListPos, List<String> crf) {
    List<String> crfLines = crf;
    int yes = 0;
    mListPosChanged = mListPos;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for (int crfLinesMainIter = begin; crfLinesMainIter < end; ) {
        System.out.println(crfLines.get(crfLinesMainIter));
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //the total number of attributes without orthographic features
        //in a crfLine excluding the class attribute is 98
        if (!crfLines.get(crfLinesMainIter).equals("") && crfLines.get(crfLinesMainIter).split("\\s").length == 98) {
            //in mList parenthesis are represented by the symbol
            //in crfLines parenthesis are represented by -LRB- or -RRB-
            //we make a check to ensure the equality is preserved
            if(val.equals(crfLines.get(crfLinesMainIter).split("\\s")[0])) {                 
                yes = checkForConsecutivePresence(crfLinesMainIter, mList, mListPos, id, crfLines);
                if (yes > 0) {
                    mListPosChanged += yes;
                    System.out.println("formCrfLinesWithMentionClass: "+mListPosChanged);
                    for (int crfLinesMentionIter = crfLinesMainIter; 
                            crfLinesMentionIter < crfLinesMainIter + yes; 
                            crfLinesMentionIter++) {
                        String valString = "";
                        if (crfLinesMentionIter == crfLinesMainIter) {
                            valString += crfLines.get(crfLinesMentionIter);
                            valString += " B";
                            crfLines.add(crfLinesMentionIter, valString);             
                        }
                        else {
                            valString += crfLines.get(crfLinesMentionIter);
                            valString += " I";                                
                            crfLines.add(crfLinesMentionIter, valString);
                        }
                    }
                    crfLinesMainIter += yes;
                }
                else {
                    ++crfLinesMainIter;
                }
            }
            else {
                ++crfLinesMainIter;
            }
        }
        else {
            ++crfLinesMainIter;
        }
    }
    return crfLines;
}
```

The problem I face is as follows:
crfLines is a List collections interface. 
When the for loop (between //-----) starts out, the crfLines.get(crfLinesMainIter) works fine. But once, it enters into the if and other processing is carried out on it, even though "crfLinesMainIter" changes the crfLines.get(crfLinesMainIter) seems to get a certain previous value. It does not retrieve the actual value at the index. Has anyone faced such a scenario? Would anyone be able to tell me why this occurs?

---

My actual question is, when does it occur that even though the indexes might be different a list.get() function still retrieves a value from before which was at another index?

For example:

List crfLines = new LinkedList<>();

if crfLinesMainIter = 2

crfLines.get(crfLinesMainIter) brings me a value say 20 and this value 20 satisfies the if loop condition. So then further processing happens. Now when the for loop executes the values of crfLinesMainIter changes to say 5. In this case, crfLines.get(5) should actually bring me a different value, but it still brings me the previous value 20.

Comment: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Technology/dp/0201485672/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1322603768&sr=8-1

Comment: Code turned on its side is not a graph of how awesome it is... I find it difficult to reason about this code at first glance.

Comment: The problem you have is not clear, and we don't know what this method is supposed to do. Have you stepped throught the code using a debugger? This would probably lead you to the explanation of the problem.

Comment: Where did you learn how to use for loop like this? This is the first time I have ever seen.

Answer (score 2):

(Not an answer.)

Reworked (more or less) for some modicum of readability:

```
private static List<String> formCrfLinesWithMentionClass(int begin, int end, String id, List<String> mList, int mListPos, List<String> crf) {
    List<String> crfLines = crf;
    mListPosChanged = mListPos;

    int i = begin;
    while (i < end) {
        if (crfLines.get(i).equals("") || (crfLines.get(i).split("\\s").length != 98)) {
            ++i;
            continue;
        }

        if (!val.equals(crfLines.get(i).split("\\s")[0])) {
            ++i;
            continue;
        }                 

        int yes = checkForConsecutivePresence(i, mList, mListPos, id, crfLines);
        if (yes <= 0) {
            ++i;
            continue;
        }

        mListPosChanged += yes;
        for (int j = i; j < i + yes; j++) {
            String valString = crfLines.get(j);
            valString += (j == i) ? " B" : " I";
            crfLines.add(j, valString);             
        }
        i += yes;
    }

    return crfLines;
}
```

- What is `mListPostChanged`? I find it confusing that it's being set to the value of a parameter named `mListPos`--it makes me think the `m` prefix is meaningless.
- What is `val` in the line containing the `split`?

Comment: My main question is, how is it that the crfLines.get(i) is not able to bring me a value at the index?

Comment: @rookie It can; it will return whatever `String` is at the index position you give it. Are you sure the list contains what you think it does? Are you sure the `begin` and `end` values are what you think they are? Are you sure `i` is what you think it is? That's the problem with code that's hard to reason about--it's difficult to answer those questions. I'd suggest stepping through some loop iterations if you're not going to make the code cleaner.

Comment: I'm sorry about the code not being clean. Its a really big program. I believe I'll step into the loop iterations. I'm pretty sure the index value is what it is and I'm sure that the contents at the different index values are different. Would it possible that because it's a linked list, if I add values to it at specific indexes, when it comes back in the for loop its lost the index orientation?

Comment: @rookie If you're changing the list you're iterating over, yeah, that'll mess up your indices, depending on where you're inserting things. In general you want to be pretty careful about ever doing anything like that.

Comment: Dave, I actually needed to use the LinkedList.set(i, val) instead of LinkedList.add(i, val). It solved the problem. Thanks for your input, even though the question wasn't very clear.

Comment: @rookie Ah, yep, very different things :) Glad you worked it out.